# Getting an image from an URL

Tags: c#, ios, swift, image, url

I'm trying to get an image from an URL in swift. The exact same method works in Xamarin (C#), but not anymore in swift. Other answers I've found don't work either (probably swift has been updated).

Debugging shows that the data is nil, but I can't understand why it would be..

This is my code in C#:

```
NSUrl url = new NSUrl ("https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t31.0-8/10688014_10152768605283809_1207583377417036990_o.jpg");
        NSData data = NSData.FromUrl (url);
        imageView.Image = new UIImage (data);
```

And this is my code in swift:

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t31.0-8/10688014_10152768605283809_1207583377417036990_o.jpg")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!, options: nil, error: nil)

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
    imageView.image = image
```

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That error option is there for a reason. Try passing an error and see if it is populated after trying to create the NSData object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSURL fileURLWithPath` takes path and not url. From NSURL documentation:

> path should be a valid system path

Try using:

```
NSURL(string: "https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t31.0-8/10688014_10152768605283809_1207583377417036990_o.jpg")
```